# Different Styles for Woocommerce Prices

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, styles, price

First of all sorry for my bad english.

On my Woocommerce Shop www.kohlekinder.com I would like to display the price labels in different designs (color/font size etc). I´ll try to explain it.

The Price on the PROUCT PAGE should have a different style than at the Shopping cart and the Checkout. I know I need to change the Classes to change the Design.

Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

to style your text you have classes or id's on your text, inside your .css file you call those classes or id's and give them styling like `color: green;` wich makes the text green. if you add some extra classes like: `.shoppingcard{}` in your css, all you need to do is add the class you want to the text your want to have that class

Comment: I know how to add and change classes  / id´s..but my problem is. I cant find the right one for this Case :(

Comment: What do you mean with the right one?, do you already have other classes but just don't now wich one to use?

Comment: The problem is that the Class for the Price is displayed on three different places..on the product page..on the shopping cart..and on the checkout..and if I change the Style he changed it ON every three Places..but I want to change/edit it seperatly..

Comment: what you can try is add a new class in your css file and put that class on the text thats on the shopping cart page and remove the other one wich is already used by the product page

Comment: Yep..and my problem is i cant identify the right one..^^

Comment: You can't identify the right place to put a new class? or on wich text a new class must be added?

Comment: Yep I cant identify the right place to add a new Class :(

Comment: when you go to your shopingcart page and have an item in there you can right click on your text that you want to change and a menu will popup, in the menu choose: inspector and a new window will appear with code inside, the highlighted blue line of code is the text that you selected(wich is probable in a <span>) in that line of code it shows you the class it has. thats the class you want to remove or overrule by a new class with !important after each style tag

Comment: no problem, glad you found what you were looking for.